# unexpected multithreaded server reaction - C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I'm working on a multithreaded server/client. The problem I have is that the server handling sometimes looks a little bit various. The message, which is send back is always correct, but the message the server prints out is a little bit weird. If it is a short word like "hello" everything works. If it is a long word or there are spaces in the string like "Binominalkoeffizient" the out-printed serversided message is:

```
Binomina
lkoeffiz
ient
fiz
```

Any idea where my mistake is?

PS: The server reaction is the same when I use telnet!

**Server-Main:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "server.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    socketStatusCheck(sock);

    puts("[*] Starting Server ...");
    puts("[*] Initialize Server ...");
    initializeServer(&server, 8888);
    bindServerToAddress(sock, server);

    puts("[*] Waiting for incomming connections ... ");
    puts("");
    listen(sock, 3);

    connectionSwitch(sock);

    close(sock);

    return 0;

}
```

**Server-File**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "server.h"


void socketStatusCheck(int sock) {
    if (sock == -1) {
        perror("Error creating the socket: ");
        exit(0);
    }
}

void initializeServer(struct sockaddr_in *server, int port) {
    server->sin_family = AF_INET;
    server->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server->sin_port = htons(port);
}

void bindServerToAddress(int sock, struct sockaddr_in server) {
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Error binding port: ");
    }
}

void connectionSwitch(int sock) {

    int nsock, lenbuf;
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    pthread_t pid = NULL;

    lenbuf = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while ((nsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &client, (socklen_t*) &lenbuf))) {
        puts("Client connected!");
        if (pthread_create(&pid, NULL, connectionHandler, (void*) &nsock))
            perror("Error creating thread: ");
    }
    if (nsock < 0) {
        perror("Error accepting incomming client: ");
    }

    pthread_exit(pid);

}

void *connectionHandler(void *sockptr) {

    int sock = *(int*) sockptr;
    long isConnected;
    char *smessage, *recvmessage;

    smessage = "Hello! I am the server you just connected! \n";
    write(sock, smessage, strlen(smessage));

    recvmessage = malloc(5000 * sizeof(char)); // while ((isConnected = recv(sock, recvmessage, sizeof(recvmessage), 0)) > 0)
    while ((isConnected = recv(sock, recvmessage, sizeof(recvmessage), 0)) > 0) {
        //write(sock, recvmessage, sizeof(recvmessage));
        send(sock, recvmessage, sizeof(recvmessage), 0);
        puts(recvmessage);
    }

    if (isConnected == 0) {
        perror("Client disconnected: ");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    free(recvmessage); recvmessage = NULL;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `free(recvmessage); recvmessage = NULL;` is pointless, remove the second statement.

Comment: Well that's because you only read 8 bytes at a time (`sizeof(recvmessage)` is 8) and you print a newline after each group of 8 bytes you read.

Answer (score 3):

This really has nothing to do with multithreading, and everything to do with the nature of `SOCK_STREAM` sockets.

Stream sockets are, as the name suggests, a stream of bytes; they do not preserve message boundaries such that what is sent with one call to `send` is received with one call to `recv`.  A single `send` may be broken up across multiple `recv` calls, or multiple `send` calls may be coalesced into a single `recv`, or both.  They do guarantee order, in that the bytes will be received in the same order they are sent.

You'll need to implement your own record marking, perhaps by inserting `\0` characters to delimit words, or by using length prefixes.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much! I will try creating such a record marking using \0

Comment: @Josey consider accepting this answer if it helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior. When you use `send` you don't know how many bytes will be sent. It may happen that all the words , characters are sent.However there are ways to solve this problem. One way is to write a simple header to the string you send , which contains the length of the string you are sending . So you know when the string is ending . For example you can use a thread to look continuously for messages and because the header contains the length of the string you know when to print a \n.The behavior of the `send` cannot be altered , because it is the Kernel , that is doing this .

Comment: Thank you too! Really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other answers say already:

Your code specifically asks to read 8 bytes at a time. `recvmessage` is a pointer, and pointers are 8 bytes on your system, so `sizeof(recvmessage)` is 8.